# How to add sqlite-jdbc jar in netbeans java application while creating a installation setup file?

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans, installation

I have created a desktop application in netbeans IDE using sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2 jar 
        and   I am using sqlite-jdbc.jar library to save and  retrieve the user data. and I 
        am trying to make a installation file using clickteam install creator software or any
        other setup installation softwares  but I dont know how to add sqlite-jdbc jar and 
        some supportive jars in the installation setup file.